# Задача про окончание урока

Tags: c++

Ребят помогите с кодом
В некоторой школе занятия начинаются в 9:00. Продолжительность урока — 45 минут, после 1-го, 3-го, 5-го и т.д. уроков перемена 5 минут, а после 2-го, 4-го, 6-го и т.д. — 15 минут. Определите, когда заканчивается указанный урок.

**Входные данные**
Дан номер урока (число от 1 до 10).

**Выходные данные**
Выведите два целых числа: время окончания урока в часах и минутах. При решении этой задачи нельзя пользоваться циклами и условными инструкциями.

Понимаю алгоритм,но не знаю как записать на С++,кто может код написать?

```
int n,k; 
cin>>n; 
k=n*45+n/2*5+(n-1)/2*15;
 cout<<9+k/60<<' '<<k%60;
```

Comment: Расскажите алгоритм

Comment: За вас код писать не будут точно. Если кто напишет, я его заминусую

Comment: я могу только на паскале,хочу понять,в чем разница на С++

Comment: если нельзя пользоваться условными операторами и циклами, то можно положиться на то, что больше 20 уроков в день не будет (с 9 утра до полуночи 15 часов). Поэтому, можно посчитать все на листике и просто с массива брать готовое.

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества вопросы не должны сводиться к завершению задач за учащихся. Приведите пример вашей реализации и задайте вопрос с описанием конкретных проблем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"russian");
    int lessonNumber, hour, minutes;
    cout<<"введите номер урока: ";
    cin >> lessonNumber;
    hour = lessonNumber * 45 + lessonNumber / 2 * 5 + (lessonNumber - 1) / 2 * 15;
    minutes = hour % 60;
    cout << "Время начала "<<lessonNumber<<" урока: "<<9 + hour/60<<" часов "<<minutes<<" минут"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Урок N заканчивается в **9:00 + N * 45 минут + K<sub>N-1</sub>** Где K<sub>N-1</sub> - сумма перемен до N-1 урока, включительно

K<sub>p</sub> можно рассчитать по двум формулам, исходя из четности p

K<sub>2k</sub> = 20 * k;
K<sub>2k + 1</sub> = 20 * k + 5;

(20 - это сумма двух перемен: 5 после нечетного урока и 15, после четного). Итого имеем такой код

```
int N;
cin >> N;
int n_2 = (N - 1) / 2;
int K = 20 * n_2;
if ((N - 1) % 2)
  K += 5;
int end = 45 * N + K;  // Количество минут до окончания N урока
int hour = 9 + end / 60;
int min = end % 60;
cout << hour << ':' << min;
```